# Mocking a repository

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

I am trying to mock a repository in symfony 2, so that I can work on a test data. The problem is that the entity manager returns empty entity object, with all values as NULL, as if it's from the real database. What's wrong here? This is the code I've written so far:

```
$user = $this->getMock('\Acme\AdminBundle\Entity\Users');
        $user->expects($this->once())
             ->method('getId')
             ->will($this->returnValue(1));
        $user->expects($this->once())
             ->method('getEmail')
             ->will($this->returnValue('aaa'));

        $userRepository = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $userRepository->expects($this->once())
            ->method('find')
            ->will($this->returnValue($user));

        $entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $entityManager->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->will($this->returnValue($userRepository));

        var_dump($entityManager->getRepository('Acme:Users')->find(1)); die();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you Mock an object like that, using `var_dump` won't work.  Read [this tutorial](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-4-mock-objects-stub-methods-dependency-injection/) for a full explanation of mocking.  Another good explanation is the [PHPUnit documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) itself.  Here's the relevant information to note:

> By default, all methods of the original class are replaced with a dummy implementation that just returns null (without calling the original method). Please note that final, private and static methods cannot be stubbed or mocked. They are ignored by PHPUnit's test double functionality and retain their original behavior.

Think of your mocked entity as an entity that behaves like your User, except every variable and every function is `null`.  That is why you had to stub individual methods to return the values that you wanted - however, they only return those values when you **call those functions directly**.  So, everything is absolutely correct in your Mocking.  If you do:

```
var_dump($theUser->getId());
var_dump($theUser->getEmail());
```

You will get the following result:

```
int(1)
string(3) "aaa"
```

This is correct - it is exactly what you Mocked.  So if you wanted to add an assertion you could do this (after removing the `var_dump` calls):

```
$this->assertSame(1, $theUser->getId());
$this->assertSame("aaa", $theUser->getEmail());
```

Note that those 2 tests wouldn't be very useful on their own because you'd essentially just be testing that PHPUnit itself works.  The point of your Mocks would be in combination with some other methods that rely on a user being fetched from the database and having a particular *id* or *email* value.